# Invoke command error, trying to get linked GPO's from specific OU from dc by script

Tags: windows, powershell, server

i have a line in PS script which goes to DC and try to do this:

```
    $SWITCH = Invoke-Command -session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter *  -Property CanonicalName | Where-Object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $using:listBox2.SelectedItem}}
```

here are the the variables:
$switch = "OU=office,DC=shahar,DC=local"
$s = credentials to enter the DC with an admin account.

if i run this line on the DC without the invoke command it works. if i run other code lines with invoking commands using these credentials it works as well.

if i run this line on powershell (not as a part of script) it works.

if i replace $switch with the actual string ("DC=...") it still doesnt work.
here is the error and i just cannot figure out whats the problem:

Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "OU=Office,DC=shahar,DC=local" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit". Error: "Cannot convert the "OU=Office,DC=shahar,DC=local"
value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit"."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrgani
   zationalUnit
    + PSComputerName        : dc01

any help would be much appriciated!

by the way the point of this is to get from the DC the GPO's names that linked to that OU.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ipmo ActiveDirectory,GroupPolicy

$OU = 'OU=office,DC=shahar,DC=local'

(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $OU).DistinguishedName
$LinkedGPOs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $OU | select -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
$LinkedGPOGUIDs = $LinkedGPOs | % {$_.Substring(4,36)}
$LinkedGPOGUIDs | % {Get-GPO -Guid $_ | select -ExpandProperty Displayname}
```